# Tomcat 7 multiple contexts

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I Have My Application "MyApp" that runs on tomcat 7 and use spring framework and have the following access URLs:

```
1 - https://localhost:8443/MyApp/      for the Application Web
2 - https://localhost:8443/MyApp/Rest  for the Application web services
```

And my application is sets on the path:

```
...\tomcat\webapps\MyApp\
```

I need to change the URLs to be without changing the application folder:

```
1 - https://localhost:8443/MyApp/Admin       for the Application Web(need to change MyApp to be Admin)
2 - https://localhost:8443/MyApp/Rest  for the Application web services
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But Tomcat should not be accessible to the public anyway, URL mangling should be done on load balancer of HTTPD levels

Answer (score 1):

Poorman's solution:

copy ROOT folder in tomcat and rename it to `Admin`, then change `index.jsp`, add this line to code:

```
response.sendRedirect("https://localhost:8443/MyApp/");
```