# Spring No mapping found for HTTP request with URI and Not Found 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am working on Spring application that was working perfectly yesterday,today when i run it,
it gave me  **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI  [/BMS/]**

and the mapping in the WEB.XML was

```
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

when i changed it to

```
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/BMS/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

it the exception gone but now its not recognizing  the `@RequestMapping` in the Controllers for example :`@RequestMapping(value="/login")` its giving **error 404 not Found**
when i change the mapping back the Controllers Works but the exception rise again

Any Hints to get rid of Both errors?

Comment: What URL are you hitting? What is `@RequestMapping` of the controller?

Comment: have you tried `{hostname}/BMS/login`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 yes its working when i call it like u say but the exception is rising when i start the application cause its the welcome page and start by loginpage not found 404

Comment: hava a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864917/tomcat-7-multiple-contexts/23865083#23865083 , just redirect to your sevlet name

Answer (score 0):

root of your application is /BMS so when application is started request goes {hostname}/BMS/
it does not find request mapping for "/" so it is giving 404.
you can specify request mapping for "{hostname}/BMS/" and redirect from  their to your url 
"{hostname}/BMS/login"